# form method POST giving me GET parameters

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I'm having a problem with form submit. When I click on the button inside the form whose method is POST it gives me GET parameters, I think the form is not executing at all.

here's my code:

```
     <form method="POST" action="profile.php" id="acc_form">
                <label> Number </label>
                <input type="text" name="number" id="number" class="form-control">
    
                <div class="text-center btn_center">
                <button type="submit" id="apply" name="apply" class="btn_1 ">APLIKO</button>
                </div>
        </form>
```

and here's my script (it has more but this is the key part WHEN boolen acc_nr_valid == true it has to submit with post method but it's giving me something like xxx.php?number=xxxx):

```
<script>
     document.querySelector("#apply").addEventListener("click", function() {
                if(acc_nr_valid == true){
                    document.getElementById("acc_form").submit();
                }else{
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });  
</script>
```

Comment: N.B. this won't actually prevent a submission because `event` is undefined. Needs to be `.addEventListener("click", function(event) {` for that to work. At worst you could even end up submitting the form twice. Even aside from that though, if you're not using preventDefault in the "true" case, you don't need to explicitly call .submit() because that's the default behaviour anyway

Comment: Anyway even without that fix, the code shown doesn't seem to reproduce the error - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v0c35z9L/ (you need to use the developer tools, to see that it definitely submits a POST).

Comment: Here's a version of the code which implements the validation and prevention of submission properly, without the redundant submit: https://jsfiddle.net/v0c35z9L/1/ . Note that it still doesn't reproduce the stated error, either, even if you make acc_nr_valid true.

Comment: it actually does prevent when the acc_nr_valid is false but however the problem is that it ish showing me like I'm doin a GET request even though I do have the method POST. I don't know if I'm being clear enough.

Comment: Yes you're being clear about the problem with the GET/POST. Unfortunately though, the code you've shown doesn't cause that problem to occur, so we can't tell you why that's happening. Either you're misinterpreting what you're seeing in your application, or the code you're running when you test is not actually the code you're showing here. You say `it's giving me something like xxx.php?number=xxxx` ...where/how exactly are you seeing that? Have you used your browser's Developer Tools to watch the Network and see what is actually going on?

Comment: You're right cause my code actually is way longer but I showed the key part. I do have some js plugins and it may cause this problem right? I'm not good with js sooo... Thank you tho

Comment: `I do have some js plugins and it may cause this problem right`...depends what they do and how they interact with your page or your form. Impossible to be sure, without knowing any details. If you need our help, then we'll need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - i.e enough code to reproduce the problem, but not too much.If you're not sure which JS is causing the issue, remove it all (and any thing else which directly depends on it, if necessary), and then add it back in again one bit at a time until you start having problems again

Comment: I feel so stupid to tell you that I found the error and the error was in my html code and not my JS one hahah I have placed the <form> inside another <form>. Thank you for your effort to help, I appreciate it.